# Standardized residual for point with 0 variance

Tags: chi-squared-test, residuals, standardization, curve-fitting

So I was fitting a curve to some data. The data looks as follows:

$E = [14.9, 22.7, 28.4, 12.5, 10.5, 14.0, 9.3, 11.5, 7.1, 22.0, 5]$

$A = [924.5, 1067.8, 1124.9, 577.0, 430.3, 880.3, 333.0, 569.3,
133.0, 1025.9, 0]$

$uA = [56, 57.2, 60.6, 81, 39, 43.1, 14.8, 43.0, 15.8, 116, 0]$

Here I want $A$ as my dependent variable, $uA$ is uncertainty of $A$ at each $E$.
I was able to determine a proper fit function, but problem comes, when I want to test the goodness of fit using $\chi^2$ test. The value of $A$ at $E = 5$ is $0$, with uncertainty $uA = 0$, which turns out problematic, when trying to compute standardized residuals.

What I've been thinking of was simply removing that point from the computation, but I think that it makes no sense, as non-standardized value of residual at this point is not zero. I also tried to standardize all values but the one for $A(E= 5)$ point, however this also doesn't seem to be a reasonable solution.

What could be a good solution here? Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: One possibility is using a very small number to replace the zero value, such as 0.000001 - I have used this technique in the past, and sometimes as a practical matter it can be useful.

Comment: Is the value $(E,A)=(5,0)$ actual data or is it based on an assumption?

Comment: @JamesPhillips - replacing zero with some small value was also my thought, but in my case it makes no sense - as residual value at that point is way above 1, dividing by that small number gives very large value, much bigger than for any other points, wheras plot indicates the residual for that point should be comparable to those computed for other points.

Comment: @whuber It's one of the values of the data I've been given for that task, which indicates we should probably treat it as actual data.

Comment: Never mind guys, I removed this whole point as an outlier for the sake of this analysis, and the whole fit gave roughly the same results and of course also let me conduct $\chi^2$ testing. I leave the question open for future reference - maybe someone will be able to provide some best practices in that situation.

Comment: Real data usually have *some* finite amount of uncertainty.  The value of $0$ assigned to it suggests you are trying to force the model to go through the point $(5,0)$.  For the approaches (and many problems) with this, please see our threads on "regression through the origin."  (The site search isn't working right now, or I would provide a link.)